# Kendo grid datetime picker , how to get timestamp?

Tags: datetime, kendo-ui, timestamp, kendo-grid

I would like to get the timestamp value from datetime picker placed in a grid data table.

I tried to do it this way:

```
  columns: ["id", 
            "username", 
            "email", 
           {
                          field :"created", 
                          title : "Created at",
                          format: "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}",
                          parseFormats: ["dd-MM-yyyy"],
                          type: "date"
           },
```

But it always returns a value like this:

```
created: "+046300-12-08T07:40:00.000Z"
```

How can I get timestamp from date picker?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/globalization/dateparsing should help

Comment: There is mainly written about parsing date to output, not from input.